# VBScript Excel Workbooks.Open Not Working When Executed from PHP Website

Tags: php, excel, vbscript

I'm attempting to run a VBScript from PHP (running under FastCGI/IIS) that modifies an xls file.

The VBScript looks like this:

```
...
        Dim objXLApp, objXLWb, objXLWs

        Set objXLApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

        objXLApp.Visible = False
        objXLApp.DisplayAlerts = False

        Set objXLWb = objXLApp.Workbooks.Open(FilePath)
        Set objXLWs = objXLWb.Worksheets(1)

        objXLWs.Cells(1, 1) = "This is a test!"

        objXLWb.Save
...
```

The test.php file looks like this:

```
<?php
echo shell_exec("cscript.exe Test.vbs test.xls");
```

If I open a console and run `php test.php` it correctly modifies the xls file, but if I reset the xls file and visit test.php in a browser window it doesn't do anything. Messing around with WShell.Echo, it seems like it crashes/stops at the `objXLApp.Workbooks.Open(FilePath)` line.

When I run this code on my local computer using `php -S` it works perfectly, it's just when running under IIS on the Windows Server 2012 host that it doesn't work.

What's causing this? Is there any way to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: Does the server have Excel installed?

Answer (score 0):

```
C:\Users\User>"C:\Users\User\Desktop\New Text Document.vbs" "C:\Users\User\Desktop\David\Documents\Payrates.xls"
```

and

```
    Set objXLWb = GetObject(WScript.Arguments(0))
    Set objXLWs = objXLWb.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    objXLWs.Cells(1, 1) = "This is a test!"
    objXLWb.Save
```

Comment: It a PHP config issue.

Comment: What users are PHP and the file.